# Trouble reallocating structure

Tags: c

I am having error massage when I try to reallocate a structure until the user decides to exit. When structure has 3 integers, I am getting
"realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)" error. But when the structure has only an integer variable, it works fine. Could you help me solve it? Here are my codes:

The code below gives error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Students{
    long int id;
    int section;
    int grade;
}Students;
void add_student(Students *myclass,int *count)
{
    printf("\nEnter id,section and grade: ");
    scanf(" %ld %d %d",&myclass[*count].id,&myclass[*count].section,&myclass[*count].grade);
}
int main()
{
    Students *myclass;
    int i,count=0,decision;
    myclass=(Students *) malloc(2*sizeof(Students));
    do{
            printf("To add press 1\nTo exit press 2: ");
            scanf(" %d",&decision);
            if(decision==1){
                    printf("In the main count is %d\n",count);
                    if(count>=2){
                            myclass=(Students *) realloc(myclass,count*sizeof(Students));
                    }
                    add_student(myclass,&count);
                    count+=1;
            }
    }while(decision!=2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code below works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct Students{
        int grade;
}Students;
void add_student(Students *myclass,int *count)
{
        printf("\nEnter grade: ");
        scanf(" %d",&myclass[*count].grade);
}
int main()
{
        Students *myclass;
        int i,count=0,decision;
        myclass=(Students *) malloc(2*sizeof(Students));
        do{
                printf("To add press 1\nTo exit press 2: ");
                scanf(" %d",&decision);
                if(decision==1){
                        printf("In the main count is %d\n",count);
                        if(count>=2){
                                myclass=(Students *) realloc(myclass,count*sizeof(Students));
                        }
                        add_student(myclass,&count);
                        count+=1;
                }
        }while(decision!=2);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know, that array index starts at 0 and you must provide memory for 3 values if you want to read in into index `[2]`, do you?

Comment: In both your codes you access the available memory out of bounds. The difference is only how far beyond you go. In both cases that is undefined behaviour and it is just by accident that one versions seems to work.

Comment: At first, I created a structure array with size 2. But the user may enter more grades than 2. So if the user decides to go on my program, should reallocate.

Comment: Aside: In C you should not cast the return value of `malloc`, `realloc` etc.. Also, why do you use a pointer `int *count` int `add_student`. You don't modify it, a simple `int` would do.

Comment: Walk through your code in debugger or maybe with pen&paper. When you enter the 3rd value, `count` will be `2`. What size will be `realloc`ed and into which index will be read?

Comment: Always check the value returned by `scanf`.   And `struct Students *a = myclass + *count;  printf("\nEnter id,section and grade: ");  if( 3 != scanf(" %ld %d %d",&a->id,&a->section,&a->grade) ){ /* Deal with input error */; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've struggled; it's plain to see.

Here's a "clean up" of your code that should get you started.

Call `realloc()` with an initially NULL pointer and it works just like `malloc()`. So, instead of *estimating* **2** to start, start with **0** and grow the array as needed. (Notice the use of `+1` and `-1` so that the 0th array element is used when there is only 1 array element in existence, 1 when there are 2, etc... Base-0 numbering for the indexes; that last index is 'n-1' when 'n' is the number of elements.

Also, add proper testing of success on all function calls. Don't presume everything will always work as you hope it to.

Finally, pay close attention to the formatting used below. Spread things out so that the code is easier to read. Use more whitespace!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int grade;
} Student;

void add_student( Student *pOneStudent ) { // NB. Only one student struct here.
    printf( "\nEnter grade: " );
    scanf( "%d", &pOneStudent->grade );
    /* omitting test for failure */
}

int main() {
    Student *myclass = NULL;
    int count = 0, decision;

    do {
        printf(
            "To add press 1\n"
            "To exit press 2: "
        );
        scanf( "%d", &decision );
        /* omitting test for failure */

        if( decision == 1 ) {
            myclass = realloc( myclass, (count + 1) * sizeof *myclass );
            /* omitting test for failure */

            count += 1;
            add_student( myclass + count - 1 ); // base 0 indexing

// print debugging
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) printf( "#%d(%d)\n", i, myclass[i].grade );

        }
    } while( decision != 2 );

    // AND, don't forget and have memory leaks.
    // When you are done with "heap storage"...
    free( myclass );

    return 0;
}
```

```
To add press 1
To exit press 2: 1

Enter grade: 75
#0(75)
To add press 1
To exit press 2: 1

Enter grade: 68
#0(75)
#1(68)
To add press 1
To exit press 2: 1

Enter grade: 23
#0(75)
#1(68)
#2(23)
To add press 1
To exit press 2: 2
```